# Keycloak user validation check via API before user self-registration

Tags: validation, keycloak, user-registration

We use Keycloak and let users self-register to our app.
We want to prevent users from using temporary emails. In order to do so, we intend on using a third-party service via API (such as [IsTempEmail](https://www.istempmail.com/user)).
We would like to be able to make the API call, ideally from the backend, to validate the form and then proceed to create the user.
If the email is a temp email, the form is not valid, the user should remain on the signup screen with an error message stating that temporary emails are not allowed.

How can I add a back-end validation such as this one for user self-registration?